# Google OAuth v2 for UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, google-oauth

I am new to OAuth verification and I have run out of options here because when I try to access the Google's OAuth screen it never provides me with the access code. I can access the login screen and then either if I choose Allow or Deny it gives me a success message. There is no error but sometimes it gives an exception of invalid protocol but I don't know why is that.

I am trying to get help from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps) and also from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/UWPWebAuthenticationBrokerA-89fd732e#content), but nothing is working.

The code that I am using is below:

```
        string state = GenerateRandomBase64Url(32);
        string code_verifier = GenerateRandomBase64Url(32);
        string code_challenge = GenerateBase64urlencodeNoPadding(sha256(code_verifier));

        string clientID = "1037832553054-2ktd0l6dop546i1ti312r2doi63sglfe.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        string redirectURI = "uwp.app:/oauth2redirect";
        string authorizationEndpoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
        string tokenEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
        string userInfoEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo";
        string youtubeScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube";
        string code_challenge_method = "S256";

        ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values["state"] = state;
        localSettings.Values["code_verifier"] = code_verifier;

        string authorizationRequest = string.Format($@"{authorizationEndpoint}?response_type=code&scope={Uri.EscapeDataString(youtubeScope)}&redirect_uri={Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI)}&client_id={clientID}&state={state}&code_challenge={code_challenge}&code_challenge_method={code_challenge_method}&login_hint={EmailBox.Text.Trim()}");

        string endURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?";
        // I don't know if this is actually valid because google says that this Url is not available
        Uri startURI = new Uri(authorizationRequest);
        Uri endURI = new Uri(endURL);
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //var success = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(authorizationRequest));

            WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startURI, endURI);
            switch (webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus)
            {
                // Successful authentication.  
                case WebAuthenticationStatus.Success:
                    result = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString();
                    break;
                // HTTP error.  
                case WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp:
                    result = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    result = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString();
                    break;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;
        }
        response.Text = result;

 // the string that I get looks like this
 // https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=410b4db829b95fce&pageId=none&xsrfsign=AMt42IIAAAAAWO9e-l2loPR2RJ4_HzjfNiGJbiESOyoh
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do it in UWP apps. Furthermore the string that I get from the result is rather just a Url and it doesn't include anything that would be considered as `code` as described in Google examples.
So can someone point out what I am doing wrong here? This should be simple but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: I have tested Google OAuth v2 for UWP by using official [code sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows). And I used `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync` to get web authentication result. But I can not reproduce your issue, Could provide me your source code so that I can do more testing on this issue ?

Comment: Well I guess it was just a problem with `?` at the end of the `endURL`, I put it here but I didn't use it in my actual code and I sorted it out somehow. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure as to how I managed to solve the problem last time as my comment suggested. `WebAuthenticationBroker` in UWP does not work that way anymore or at least I think so. It actually asks for a `startURL` and a `callbackURL`.

I came across the same problem, as in my question, yesterday and I solved it through putting my app's `redirectUri` in the place of `callbackURL` and `WebAuthenticationBroker` does not throw an exception anymore and it provides a successful result.

So to solve the problem, this is how you would do it:

```
string redirectURI = "uwp.app:/oauth2redirect";

Uri startURI = new Uri(authorizationRequest); // as in the question
Uri endURI = new Uri(redirectUri); // change to 'redirectUri'
WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startURI, endURI);
switch(webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus)
{
      case WebAuthenticationStatus.Success:
      break;
}
```

I hope it helps someone out there. Thanks